# Celery tasks don't run in PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, pydev, celery, django-celery, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm and have noticed when I attach a debugger to a celery worker process that my tasks do not complete and this error is logged to the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pydevd
```

This message is logged as well when a celery task is invoked:

`[2013-03-24 05:24:26,336: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: celery.group[91218981-204a-414c-a674-fcd8e2b22d23]`

However, this task never actually completes.

This is the actual command used to attach the pydevd debugger in PyCharm to my celery worker process:

`/home/scottc/venv/myproj/bin/python home/scottc/.IntelliJIdea12/config/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 60283 --file manage.py celeryd -E -B --loglevel=INFO`

When I simply the run the process without attaching a debugger in PyCharm, the ImportError message is never displayed and my tasks do completes.

Finally, I know that pydevd is found in my path because I can manually enter in the following to my code:

```
from pydev import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('my_host', port=5643, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

and a debugger will successfully attach. The problem is, however, this is far less convenient than setting some breakpoints and clicking 'debug' in PyCharm.

Comment: Try raising the issue at the [official bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: I don't suppose you've gotten this working with celery (instead of django-celery)?  I'd buy beer for instructions.

Comment: I think all seemed to work out fine once I used the most recent versions. Also, Celery has moved away from django-celery (it's not really needed anymore unless you want to use django db for storing tasks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue went away when I upgraded celery and billiards:

```
billiard==2.7.3.23
celery==3.0.17
```

Answer (score 4):

For debugging celery, I find it simpler to add the following config:

```
from celery import current_app
current_app.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
current_app.conf.CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

This makes celery run in the same thread as the currently executing thread.